# updating List of tuples

Tags: scala, lambda, collections, functional-programming, tuples

I am new to Scala. I have a list of tuples. I want to be able to change the last element of that list to `(x, y + 1)` and then map every other element to the next one.

```
val l1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3))
```

So I need list `l2`, which after mapping should contain elements `(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4)`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analog *Andronicust* answer I prefer this style:

```
l1.map{ case (x, y) => (x, y + 1) }
```

So you can *Pattern Match* on the pairs and give the elements proper names.

In contrast to `t._1` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the list like this:

```
l1.map(t => (t._1, t._2 + 1))
```

This maps every tuple in the list into tuple with first element unchanged and second incremented by one.

Result:

> List((0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4))

Answer (score 2):

[Parameter Untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html) from **Scala 3** might give the following syntax where we no longer have to use pattern matching or `._1` syntax

```
l.map((x, y) => (x, y + 1))
```